# libpcre.so segfault/Segmentation fault - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Browser

Tags: php, apache, magento, segmentation-fault

I have a Magento 1.9 shop on a Ubuntu server - it has run without any problems for about a year. When I now open /cron.php in my Chrome browser, I get the following error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I have looked into my apache errors log. It says:

> [core:notice] [pid 1992] AH00051: child pid 2083 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

... everytime when I try to load the cron.php script.

My syslog shows the following error:

> kernel: [  774.131560] php[2406]: segfault at 7ffc036eceb8 ip
>   00007f7c1fd7a55a sp 00007ffc036eceb0 error 6 in
>   libpcre.so.3.13.1[7f7c1fd67000+3d000]

I've found out, that the error occurs at a recursive function in my php script. The function looks quite ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the PHP script had a recurive function with an infinite loop under certain conditions. I would have thought this would just lead to a script timeout. Maybe someone can explain in detail...